# How can I optimise my Python array to Pandas DataFrame conversion?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python array, that I want to convert to a Pandas DataFrame. I wrote some code for it, but it is very slow.
Any suggestions on how I can make it faster?

This is what the contents of the Python array generally look like:

```
[[1523937720000, '0.01000000', '0.01000000', '0.01000000', '0.01000000', '2278.69000000', 1523937779999, '22.78690000', 2, '346.19000000', '3.46190000', '0'], [1523937780000, '0.01000000', '0.02500000', '0.01000000', '0.01404000', '838.33000000', 1523937839999, '12.48726080', 6, '100.00000000', '2.50000000', '0']]
```

I created a DataFrame for it:

```
pandaresult = pd.DataFrame(columns=['open_time','open','close','high','low','volume','close_time','quote_volume','trades','tbbav','tbqav']).astype({'open_time':'datetime64[ms]','close':'float_', 'high':'float_','low':'float_','volume':'float_','close_time':'datetime64[ms]','quote_volume':'float_','trades':'float_','tbbav':'float_','tbqav':'float_'})
```

This is the code that fills the DataFrame:

```
for index, line in enumerate(result):
    pandaresult = pandaresult.append({'open_time':(pd.to_datetime(line[0], unit='ms')),'open':float(line[1]),'close':float(line[2]),'high':float(line[3]),'low':float(line[4]),'volume':float(line[5]),'close_time':(pd.to_datetime(line[6], unit='ms')),'quote_volume':float(line[7]),'trades':float(line[8]),'tbbav':float(line[9]),'tbqav':float(line[10])}, ignore_index=True)
```

What can I do to make it faster?

Comment: So those arrays are in a file? Cant you just do `pd.DataFrame(result,columns= pandaresult.columns)` Then use `pd.to_datetime`,`.astype(float)` over the respective dataframe columns?

Comment: The results are in memory and generated by another function. Sounds like a good idea, I will try it.

Comment: Have you looked at generating the DataFrame in one call instead of using iteration? See examples here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: Thanks, I looked at it, but I don't know how to do it in one call.